# Sets and elements confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> A, B and C are three sets. A is an element of B, B is a subset of C. Is A a subset of C?

I believe A is a subset of C, but the answers say it is not.
Consider this:- Set A contains natural numbers and B contains whole numbers. C is the set of real numbers. So Set A must be a subset of set C.

Comment: $A\in B\subset C\implies A\in C$ or, in other words, $\{A\}\subset C.$

Comment: In your example, $A$ is a subset of $B$, not an element of $B$.

Comment: $A$ _could_ be a subset of $C$, for example when $A=\{42\}$, $B=\{\{42\}\}$, $C=\{42,\{42\}\}$. The point of the exercise, however, is to see that $A$ is not _necessarily_ a subset of $C$, given the information in the exercise.

Comment: @HenningMakholm why isnt it necessarily a subset. can you provide an example sir.

Comment: @RamKeswani: An example where $A$ is not a subset of $C$ would be $A=\{42\}$, $B=\{\{42\}\}$, $C=\{108,\{42\}\}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sir i dont get what differences brackets make.

Comment: @RamKeswani: Set brackets make a set. $42$ is the _number_ forty-two. $\{42\}$ is the _set_ that has as its only element the number forty-two. Those are two _completely_ different things.

Comment: And you shouldn't "sir" random people on the internet who are only trying to help you; that's rather rude! (I am neither a customer in your business nor your military superior).

Comment: @HenningMakholm sorry I didnt meant to be rude. I just wanted to show respect. Sorry.